# Randomizing an array of C strings

Tags: c, arrays

I'm having a problem with a function meant to insert random C-strings into an array. I've read a few other questions about this on stackexchange, but none seem to work for me.

```
void rand(const char *tab[], int n){
    int i, j;
    char c[10];
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        for(j=0; j<10; j++){
            c[j]= rand()%26 + 97;
        }
        tab[i]=c;
    }
}
```

When trying to print it out, I get a blank screen, as if the array is empty. I declared the array as `const char *tab[]` and use the function `rand(tab, 5)`. What could be wrong?

Comment: `c` is a local variable. It has no meaning outside the function, and dereferencing its copied value outside the function results in undefined behaviour.

Comment: your question is very confusing. we can't know exactly what you want. what does `n` mean?

Comment: I'm sorry about that. `n` is the ammount of string that are supposed to be generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to make a copy of the generated string. and you need a string terminator

```
void rand(const char *tab[], int n){
    int i, j;
    char c[10];
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        for(j=0; j<9; j++){
            c[j]= rand()%26 + 97;
        }
      c[9] = '\0';
        tab[i]=strdup(c) <<<<=====
    }
}
```

the strings are allocated on the heap - free them when you are finised

```
for(int i=0; i < NO_STRINGS; i++)
{
   free(tab[i]);
}
```

Comment: remember to free the strings after

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean by "free the strings"?